# Re-enable animated GIF display in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, about-config

I'm using Firefox 2.0.0.17. I had disabled image looping (GIF animation) so that images only looped once. Now I want to turn the default looping behavior back on, so I reset `image.animation_mode` back to `normal` in the `about:config` window.

But this does not work; Firefox is still looping animated images only once. Is there another setting I need to set to restore the default image looping behavior?

**UPDATE**

My wife and kids also use the same Firefox on the same PC, and their image looping works fine. I never changed their settings from the default behavior, though. So when changing my setting and then back again, there must be something else that needs to be reset in my Firefox profile. I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Animated_images_in_RSS_feeds_%28Thunderbird%29)

In Mozilla Suite and Firefox:

1. In the Location Bar type about:config and hit Enter
2. Type "anim" in the Filter field (to quickly find the needed preference)
3. Double-click the image.animation_mode line and edit it to one of the following:

   ```
   none — will prevent image animation 
   once — will let the image animate once 
   normal (default) — will allow it to play over and over
   ```

(or)

> For Mozilla Suite/SeaMonkey, under "Privacy & Security -> Images", make sure that "Accept all images" is selected.
>
> Also, under "Advanced -> Scripts & Plugins", make sure that "Enable JavaScript for" "Navigator" (or "Browser") is checked and make sure that, under "Allow scripts to:", a checkmark is included next to "Change images".

Comment: The OP states that he's change the mode back to normal.

Comment: Yes, that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

With image.animation_mode back to normal, the GIF should be playing.

It might be that an external program or an add-on are blocking the play.
Check if the play is perhaps being blocked by:

1. if an add-on such as Adblock
2. A firewall or other security program.

Comment: Can't be this because image looping works fine the same Firefox browser  but with a different user profile (see update in the question).

Comment: This seems to exclude point 2. Point 1 can still be valid with either (1) You've tweaked some other undocumented setting, or (2) an add-on that works per profile. But why don't you simply uninstall FF2, clear out all its directories and install FF3.5?

Comment: Yep, *some* day.